# How long is a driving license obtained through 30% ruling valid in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, driving-license

I'm trying to exchange my driving license in the Netherlands through 30% ruling, but my current Iranian driving license is going to **expire in less than a year**.

1. Would that affect how long my Dutch driving license is going to be valid?
2. Would it be wise to first try to renew it in my origin country and then try to get the Dutch driving license?

Comment: Since you no longer live in Iran, a renewal there is normally not possible. Your dutch driving-license will not be based on how long your previous license is valid.

Comment: It is possible to renew it in Iran at least for my case, I already made sure of that. But this seems like an answer if you also have a source for that it would be nice to post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your Iranian driving license is still valid when you apply for your Dutch exchange one you are good to go, no need to extend it.

[This site](https://www.30percentruling.com/driving-license/) explains all in English.

Be prepared for a period in which you do not have a driving license, as between when you hand in the old one and when you receive the new one you are not allowed to drive.

Comment: So I already got through the process, and it take 3-4 weeks  to get the dutch one which is the period I couldn't drive